# Javascript sorting list of arraylist of object - based on specfic arraylist

Tags: javascript, sorting, arraylist

If i have the Javascript object :

```
var myObject = {
dataset : [],
};

myObject.dataset.push({data : [1,5,4,6]});
myObject.dataset.push({data : [2,4,7,4]});
myObject.dataset.push({data : [12,53,4,45]});
```

And then i want to sort **ALL** the datasets.data **BUT** only based on a specific one. fx the first one. *myObject.dataset[0].data*

expected result :

```
0 : ({data : [1,4,5,6]}); // sorted list
1 : ({data : [2,7,4,4]}); // others match the changes.
2 : ({data : [12,4,53,45]});
```

something like:

```
for(i = 0; i < myObject.dataset.length; i++) {
  myObject.dataset[i].data.sort( BASED ON myObject.dataset[0].data )
}
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lc7bn7hq/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it.  I added comments to show what's going on...

```
var something = {
    dataset: [],
};


something.dataset.unshift({data : [1,5,4,6]});
something.dataset.unshift({data : [1,5,8,6]});
something.dataset.unshift({data : [2,4,7,4]});
something.dataset.unshift({data : [12,53,4,45]});
something.dataset.unshift({data : [11,52,41,16]});
something.dataset.unshift({data : [1,53,43,64]});
something.dataset.unshift({data : [1,5,8,6,3]});

//This function is used when sorting two cells in an array
//See the Array.prototype.sort method on MDN for more info
//Returning -1 keeps (a,b)->(a,b), returning 1 swaps (a,b)->(b,a)
var asc = function(a,b) {return a<b?-1:1; };

//Sort the whole dataset, based on the values of each array
something.dataset.sort(function(a,b) {

  //The arguments a and b are cell objects in something.dataset
  //Sort each of the data arrays for the objects
  a.data.sort(asc);
  b.data.sort(asc);

  //Tricky part is if a.data[0] and b.data[0] are equal
  //Find the first cell of both arrays that are not equal
  var i=0; 
  var al = a.data.length;
  var bl = b.data.length
  var l=Math.min(al,bl);
  while(i<l && a.data[i]===b.data[i]) i++;

  //All the values for the shortest of both arrays are equal! Sort by the length of the arrays instead
  if(i>=l) return asc(al,bl);

  //We found a non-equal cell in both arrays, sort by it!
  return asc(a.data[i],b.data[i]);

});

console.log(JSON.stringify(something));
```

Comment: thanks alot, - would you mind explaining some of the code by adding comments? fx the asc function

Comment: I added some comments -  I hope it clears things up.  The native Array sorting in Javascript is quirky, so I recommend reading up on it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: Sure does, thanks a lot for the effort and time it took to comment/explain

Comment: one thing i noticed from this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/Lc7bn7hq/2/ is that the order gets changed ? can this be avoided

Comment: Ah yes, it can.  The array sort is a mutable method.  To keep the order but perform the compare, you can do this instead: var c=a.slice(); c.sort(asc); var d=b.slice(); d.sort(asc); ...then compare c and d values.

Comment: I think this does something completely different than asked in the question. This sorts each array in `dataset[n].data`, then sorts dataset by comparing the arrays in `.data` item-per-item.

Answer (score 1):

This solution reshuffles the data into a new array of arrays, sorts them and moves the data back:

```
 var regrouped=[];

 for (var i=0; i<myObject.dataset[0].data.length; i++) {
    regrouped.push([]);
 }

     for (var j=0; j<myObject.dataset[0].data.length; j++) {   
    for (i=0; i<myObject.dataset.length; i++) {
       regrouped[j][i]=myObject.dataset[i].data[j];
    }
 }

 regrouped.sort(function(a,b){return a[0]-b[0];});

 for (i=0; i<myObject.dataset.length; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<myObject.dataset[0].data.length; j++) {   
       myObject.dataset[i].data[j]=regrouped[j][i];
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to use lodash or underscore js libraries .You can use this lodash function to achieve what you want pretty simply and elegantly.

```
 var something = {
    dataset: [],
};


something.dataset.unshift({data : [1,5,4,6]});
something.dataset.unshift({data : [2,4,7,4]});
something.dataset.unshift({data : [12,53,4,45]});
something.dataset.unshift({data : [11,52,41,16]});
something.dataset.unshift({data : [1,53,43,64]});


_.forEach(something.dataset, function(data){
             console.log(data.data);
           data.data =  _.sortBy(data.data);
 });

console.log(something);
```

Comment: I don't think this is what is asked in the question.

Comment: Just as alternative sir !